# How can I format a String, which is a date, to a new date format in Java?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I will get straight to the point, my goal it so change

> 2018-05-24

Into

> May 24, 2018.

Here is my current code:

```
    String content = "2018-05-24";
    SimpleDateFormat old = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date oldDate = old.parse(content);
    SimpleDateFormat current = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy.");
    String newDate = current.format(oldDate);
    System.out.println(newDate);
```

But running that produces:

> January 24, 2018.

I am not sure why this is telling me January. I know I have it wrong, I have searched StackOverFlow for similar questions, but maybe I am not doing something right. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `mm` for month when it should be `MM`:

```
SimpleDateFormat old = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This outputs:

```
May 24, 2018.
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Such a stupid mistake on my behalf.